# error in excel if or statement

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to hide the rows with the string 'hello' or 'hi'. but i get a syntax error on the if statement. but it looks right to me, any thought?

here is my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim BeginRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim ChkCol As Integer

    BeginRow = 1 'starting row
    ChkCol = 2  'column you want to check
    EndRow = Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count 'get the total number of rows

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If (OR(Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "hello", Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "hi")) Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True  'hide rows
        End If
    Next RowCnt

End Sub
```

Comment: did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "hello" Or Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "hi" Then
    Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True  'hide rows
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, doesn't look right. VBA code has its own syntax, there's no `Or` function in VBA, the language uses *logical operators* instead.

This:

```
If (OR(Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "hello", Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "hi")) Then
```

Should read like this:

```
If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "hello" Or Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = "hi" Then
```